# How to use mysql reserved keywords as column in where statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

MYSQL won't let queries select rows when the column name is a mysql keyword in the where statement.

I'm creating a php api where it grabs a username that is attached to a key provided by the user but when it's grabbing the username it can't search for it using `key == '$key'` because "key" is a reserved MySQL word that the frontend generates (and it can't be changed.)

I've tried surrounding the column name in "s, 's, `s, and []s, none of which have worked. If anyone could help me that would be great.

```
$key = $_GET['key'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM discordlink WHERE key = '$key'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

It should be able to find the row attached to the key using the where clause provided but it doesn't becuase it's a mysql reserved keyword.

Comment: Just don't do it

Comment: @Rishi, @Starwberry Please read the entire question! (I've already tried `s and I can't change it because I can't edit the system that generates the codes ingame.)

Answer (score 2):

You can surround the column name with backticks(`) for the reserved mysql words

```
SELECT `key` FROM `table`
```

Comment: 1. The problem is with the WHERE statement.

Comment: Sample statement with where : SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `key` = 'some value'

Answer (score 0):

Bit late answer, but still there was no accepted answer I am adding this answer.

We can give alias name for table and refer reserved keyword column in `WHERE` statement i.e

```
SELECT * FROM discordlink AS d WHERE d.key = '$key'
```